# Conditional replacement of variables in a "tree structure" dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I have some data on income at different government levels, over a time period of *n* years. The are two levels of government, *1* and *2*. Level *2* is the level at which I will need to carry the analysis once I set up the data, meaning the final sample will only include level 2 regional governments. Level 2 governments "belong" to the corresponding level 1 government: e.g. DE1 is the level 1, DE1x are the level 2 sub regional governments under the DE1 umbrella. This pattern is consistent in the dataset (e.g. CZ1x belong to CZ1, IT3x belong to IT3 and so on and so forth). The data can be thought of as having a tree structure. Country codes are also available and are given by the first two letters of the government levels. Data look like this :

```
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("DE1", "DE1", "DE1", "DE11", "DE11", "DE11", "DE12", "DE12", "DE12", "DE2",
            "DE2","DE2", "DE21","DE21","DE21","DE22","DE22","DE22","DE23","DE23","DE23",
            "CZ0", "CZ0","CZ0", "CZ01", "CZ01","CZ01", "CZ02", "CZ02","CZ02") , 
            c(rep("DE",21), rep("CZ",9)),
            c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1",
              "1","1", "2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",
              "1", "1","1", "2", "2","2", "2", "2","2"),
          c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2000", "2001", "2002","2000", "2001", "2002",
            "2000", "2001", "2002","2000", "2001", "2002","2000", "2001", "2002",
            "2000", "2001", "2002", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2000", "2001", "2002",
            "2000", "2001", "2002"),
            c( runif(n = 3, min = 1300, max = 21220), "NA","NA", 16000, 
          runif(n=12, min = 1300, max = 21220), "NA", 18000,"NA", runif(n=6, min = 1300, max = 21220),
          "NA","NA","NA")))

colnames(data) <- c("Region", "Country", "Gvt Lvl","Time", "Revenue")

data
Region Country Gvt Lvl Time          Revenue
DE1       DE       1   2000 16858.6538477242
DE1       DE       1   2001  7788.3873622492
DE1       DE       1   2002 19988.1219627894
DE11      DE       2   2000               NA
DE11      DE       2   2001               NA
DE11      DE       2   2002            16000
DE12      DE       2   2000 6660.73037594557
DE12      DE       2   2001 9005.15880053863
DE12      DE       2   2002 2322.38461054862
DE2       DE       1   2000 16887.0197726786
DE2       DE       1   2001 11184.8074057698
DE2       DE       1   2002 1442.17075794935
DE21      DE       2   2000 6902.39389214665
DE21      DE       2   2001 6562.93060332537
DE21      DE       2   2002 17302.4776424281
DE22      DE       2   2000 16508.5772226751
DE22      DE       2   2001 2753.07780653238
DE22      DE       2   2002 2198.10680534691
DE23      DE       2   2000               NA
DE23      DE       2   2001            18000
DE23      DE       2   2002               NA
CZ0       CZ       1   2000 8614.85693316907
CZ0       CZ       1   2001 9601.59771829844
CZ0       CZ       1   2002 7134.94570834562
CZ01      CZ       2   2000 8562.89313737303
CZ01      CZ       2   2001 10880.8537839726
CZ01      CZ       2   2002  6957.3313607648
CZ02      CZ       2   2000               NA
CZ02      CZ       2   2001               NA
CZ02      CZ       2   2002               NA
```

There are cases in which data are missing at level 2, either for all years or for just some of them. When this happens, I would like to replace the NA at the lower level of government (2) with the values observed at the corresponding higher level (1) for that missing year, if available.

I guess something reading the first three strings of the *Region* may do the trick, but I am struggling to come up with a working solution. I have 9000+ observations (rows) in my sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fill` to fill the missing values after extracting the common part from the `Region` :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Revenue = as.numeric(na_if(Revenue, "NA"))) %>%
  group_by(group = substr(Region, 1, 3), Time) %>%
  mutate(Revenue = replace(Revenue, is.na(Revenue),Revenue[Region == group])) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 30 x 6
#   Region Country `Gvt Lvl` Time  Revenue group
#   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
# 1 DE1    DE      1         2000   13259. DE1  
# 2 DE1    DE      1         2001   16229. DE1  
# 3 DE1    DE      1         2002   19929. DE1  
# 4 DE11   DE      2         2000   13259. DE1  
# 5 DE11   DE      2         2001   16229. DE1  
# 6 DE11   DE      2         2002   16000  DE1  
# 7 DE12   DE      2         2000    2793. DE1  
# 8 DE12   DE      2         2001    3491. DE1  
# 9 DE12   DE      2         2002   14854. DE1  
#10 DE2    DE      1         2000    3976. DE2  
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: hello, thank you. The final result you show is not as it should be. CZ02 in 2000 should have the same value CZ0 in 2000, the same value of CZ0 in 2001 and the same value of CZ0 in 2002. Am I overlooking anything ?

Comment: @Bob Can you take a look at the updated answer and check if that is what you were looking for?

Comment: It seems it works. Does Revenue[Region == group] work also if all level 2 observations are NA, e.g. both DE11 and DE12 for the three years? I am going to try to apply it to my dataset

Comment: Yes it should work as far as you have value for `Gvt Lvl = 1`

Comment: Yes, it seems it does properly. Could you please tell me what it does exactly for lvl 1 gvt with NA ? Does it just replace NA with itself?

Comment: Yes, it will replace it with `NA`. basically whatever value is present in `Gvt Lvl = 1` it will replace with that value.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 4.0.4

set.seed(42)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("DE1", "DE1", "DE1", "DE11", "DE11", "DE11", "DE12", "DE12", "DE12", "DE2",
                              "DE2","DE2", "DE21","DE21","DE21","DE22","DE22","DE22","DE23","DE23","DE23",
                              "CZ0", "CZ0","CZ0", "CZ01", "CZ01","CZ01", "CZ02", "CZ02","CZ02") , 
                            c(rep("DE",21), rep("CZ",9)),
                            c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1",
                              "1","1", "2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",
                              "1", "1","1", "2", "2","2", "2", "2","2"),
                            c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2000", "2001", "2002","2000", "2001", "2002",
                              "2000", "2001", "2002","2000", "2001", "2002","2000", "2001", "2002",
                              "2000", "2001", "2002", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2000", "2001", "2002",
                              "2000", "2001", "2002"),
                            c( runif(n = 3, min = 1300, max = 21220), NA,NA, 16000, 
                               runif(n=12, min = 1300, max = 21220), NA, 18000,NA, runif(n=6, min = 1300, max = 21220),
                               NA,NA,NA)))

colnames(data) <- c("Region", "Country", "Gvt Lvl","Time", "Revenue")

setDT(data)

data[,level1:=substr(Region,1,3)][]
#>     Region Country Gvt Lvl Time          Revenue level1
#>  1:    DE1      DE       1 2000 19522.9363864474    DE1
#>  2:    DE1      DE       1 2001 19966.5422328934    DE1
#>  3:    DE1      DE       1 2002 6999.89953294396    DE1
#>  4:   DE11      DE       2 2000             <NA>    DE1
#>  5:   DE11      DE       2 2001             <NA>    DE1
#>  6:   DE11      DE       2 2002            16000    DE1
#>  7:   DE12      DE       2 2000 17842.5167112611    DE1
#>  8:   DE12      DE       2 2001 14083.5707363486    DE1
#>  9:   DE12      DE       2 2002 11640.3913066722    DE1
#> 10:    DE2      DE       1 2000  15972.839227654    DE2
#> 11:    DE2      DE       1 2001 3982.55861697719    DE2
#> 12:    DE2      DE       1 2002 14387.2864248045    DE2
#> 13:   DE21      DE       2 2000  15344.890498016    DE2
#> 14:   DE21      DE       2 2001 10418.2161828689    DE2
#> 15:   DE21      DE       2 2002 15624.7160529159    DE2
#> 16:   DE22      DE       2 2000 19918.6711632833    DE2
#> 17:   DE22      DE       2 2001 6388.14218087122    DE2
#> 18:   DE22      DE       2 2002 10508.8730250672    DE2
#> 19:   DE23      DE       2 2000             <NA>    DE2
#> 20:   DE23      DE       2 2001            18000    DE2
#> 21:   DE23      DE       2 2002             <NA>    DE2
#> 22:    CZ0      CZ       1 2000 20025.0892932899    CZ0
#> 23:    CZ0      CZ       1 2001 20786.2704534456    CZ0
#> 24:    CZ0      CZ       1 2002 3640.34824416041    CZ0
#> 25:   CZ01      CZ       2 2000 10761.9418646954    CZ0
#> 26:   CZ01      CZ       2 2001 12461.8283051997    CZ0
#> 27:   CZ01      CZ       2 2002 19308.3052349649    CZ0
#> 28:   CZ02      CZ       2 2000             <NA>    CZ0
#> 29:   CZ02      CZ       2 2001             <NA>    CZ0
#> 30:   CZ02      CZ       2 2002             <NA>    CZ0
#>     Region Country Gvt Lvl Time          Revenue level1

data[data[`Gvt Lvl`==1],Revenue:=fcoalesce(Revenue,i.Revenue), on=.(level1,Time)][]
#>     Region Country Gvt Lvl Time          Revenue level1
#>  1:    DE1      DE       1 2000 19522.9363864474    DE1
#>  2:    DE1      DE       1 2001 19966.5422328934    DE1
#>  3:    DE1      DE       1 2002 6999.89953294396    DE1
#>  4:   DE11      DE       2 2000 19522.9363864474    DE1
#>  5:   DE11      DE       2 2001 19966.5422328934    DE1
#>  6:   DE11      DE       2 2002            16000    DE1
#>  7:   DE12      DE       2 2000 17842.5167112611    DE1
#>  8:   DE12      DE       2 2001 14083.5707363486    DE1
#>  9:   DE12      DE       2 2002 11640.3913066722    DE1
#> 10:    DE2      DE       1 2000  15972.839227654    DE2
#> 11:    DE2      DE       1 2001 3982.55861697719    DE2
#> 12:    DE2      DE       1 2002 14387.2864248045    DE2
#> 13:   DE21      DE       2 2000  15344.890498016    DE2
#> 14:   DE21      DE       2 2001 10418.2161828689    DE2
#> 15:   DE21      DE       2 2002 15624.7160529159    DE2
#> 16:   DE22      DE       2 2000 19918.6711632833    DE2
#> 17:   DE22      DE       2 2001 6388.14218087122    DE2
#> 18:   DE22      DE       2 2002 10508.8730250672    DE2
#> 19:   DE23      DE       2 2000  15972.839227654    DE2
#> 20:   DE23      DE       2 2001            18000    DE2
#> 21:   DE23      DE       2 2002 14387.2864248045    DE2
#> 22:    CZ0      CZ       1 2000 20025.0892932899    CZ0
#> 23:    CZ0      CZ       1 2001 20786.2704534456    CZ0
#> 24:    CZ0      CZ       1 2002 3640.34824416041    CZ0
#> 25:   CZ01      CZ       2 2000 10761.9418646954    CZ0
#> 26:   CZ01      CZ       2 2001 12461.8283051997    CZ0
#> 27:   CZ01      CZ       2 2002 19308.3052349649    CZ0
#> 28:   CZ02      CZ       2 2000 20025.0892932899    CZ0
#> 29:   CZ02      CZ       2 2001 20786.2704534456    CZ0
#> 30:   CZ02      CZ       2 2002 3640.34824416041    CZ0
#>     Region Country Gvt Lvl Time          Revenue level1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>